# Setting data properties on child components in Vue 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In Vue I have made a multipage questionnaire using `v-show` with the make app container being called `RiskAssessmentTest.vue`.

I have a component to load questionnaire drafts called `RiskAssessmentDrafts.vue` that looks like this

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block rounded" @click="loadDraft(draft)">Continue</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Progress from 'easy-circular-progress';
    import moment from 'moment';

    export default {
        components: {
            Progress
        },
        data() {
            return {
                moment: moment
            };
        },
        props: ['drafts'],
        methods: {
            loadDraft(draft) {
                this.$emit('load-draft', draft);
            },
        }
    };
</script>

<style></style>
```

The `loadDraft()` method is called in the parent component like this

```
<template>
<risk-assessment-drafts :drafts="drafts" @load-draft="loadDraftAnswers" />
</template
```

The `loadDraftAnswers()` methods grabs the data for the questionnaire and loads it into the child component.

```
/**
 * Load any draft answers into each question page.
 *
 * @param {*} $draft
 */
async loadDraftAnswers($draft) {
    this.$refs.q1.loadDraftAnswers($draft['test_id'], 0);
    this.$refs.q2.loadDraftAnswers($draft['test_id'], 1);
    this.$refs.q3.loadDraftAnswers($draft['test_id'], 2);
    this.$refs.q4.loadDraftAnswers($draft['test_id'], 3);
    this.$refs.q5.loadDraftAnswers($draft['test_id'], 4);
},
```

I don't know if its good or bad practice but I then call the `loadDraftAnswers()` method in the child component.

```
/**
 * Method called from child that loads into respective draft answers.
 *
 * @param String $testid
 * @param String $question
 *
 * @return void
 */
loadDraftAnswers($testid, $question) {
    axios
        .get(`/risk-assessment-test/get-draft-answers/${$testid}/${$question}`)
        .then((response) => {
    
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
},
```

Now to my knowledge this work, as you can see items set on the component in the Chrome dev tools.

[image]

However, when I click on the component again in Chrome dev tools, everything is unset.

[image]

Is this expected behaviour? How can I make the component retain it's data?

I ask as in the child component I use `v-if` in places but obviously after initially working everything is null again.

I made a little video too: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/13255023?key=b841eb39bee6c33b3f79ccfc199f8d80

Comment: What I got from your question is that you are calling the parent from the child component and then the parent fetches the data and set it in the child component, is it?

Comment: You have way too much code here. Someone willing to help would need to understand all your business logic which appears to be mostly irrelevant for what you're asking. Why not create the most minimal example for the pattern you're asking about? An empty parent with a child with only one data prop. On that example, explain what's the desired behavior and once you have your answer you can apply it to your more complex implementation.

Comment: An additional benefit of simplifying the example is that, most likely, anyone needing a similar pattern will upvote your question in the future, whereas, if you leave it in current form, they'll likely skip your question searching for similar ones, which require less effort to understand.

Comment: I have removed most of the redundant code.

Comment: @NehaSoni kind of, I'm using $ref to call methods on the child components, but yes, its supposed to set data properties for each child.

Comment: If possible, you can use Vuex to save data in the state, so you don't need to pass that many events from parent to child and vice versa and data will always be available. On another hand, if Vuex is not possible, You can use `eventBus` to notify the child from the parent to do some actions. Using refs to call child component methods can have other consequences as refs are not available in some circumstances.

Comment: you can use loadDraftAnswers function 1 function that is simple and easy

Comment: Thank you for all the comments so far, I'm going to try and few different things and come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that I was using a `v-if` in a separate area of the same template and for reasons I don't quite understand it was destroying the first and last page components.

So in essence the data was being loaded into the component and then the component was immediately destroyed so Vue either had nothing to push the data to, or it would add it to what it thought was the first page even though it was actually the second.

I stumbled across the issue by logging in the lifcycle events `created` and `destroyed`

```
created() {
    // console.log('Page ' + this.current_page + ' was created in the created hook');
},

destroyed() {
    // console.log('Page ' + this.current_page + ' was destroyed');
},
```

This is probably a rookie error but just in case anyone experiences something similar, this was what helped me.

(As well as the comments above).